# Predicting future coastlines based on TIN/Raster DEM and elevated polygon using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d-analyst, intersect, tin

I am trying to figure out how I can create projected future coastlines by intersecting an elevated polygon (representing future sea level) with the TIN/DEM of my study area.

Does anybody know how I could accomplish this?

Ideally, I'd like to create a polyline feature where the elevated polygon intersects with my surface model.

I am using ArcMap 10.8

Comment: Generate contours of the future sea levels using your surface model and the contour list tool.  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/contour-list.htm

Comment: That was an even simpler solution than I thought, thank you that should work perfectly!